# Occassional $compile:tpload errors

Tags: angularjs, azure, routes

I have an application that logs angular errors to a database, and I am seeing occassional logs of this error

> Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$compile/tpload?p0=app%2Fmyroute%2Fpmyroute.html&p1=-1&p2=

When going to the site the route and template load just fine, but these errors are happening and I would like to know why. Here is that route in my config.route.js

```
{
            url: '/',
            config: {
                title: 'My Route',
                templateUrl: 'app/myroute/myroute.html',
                settings: {
                    nav: 9,
                    content: '<span class="mg-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><h5 class="mg-nav-text">My Route</h5>'
                }
            }
        }
```

The website is hosted in Azure but is AlwaysOn if that matters.
Would there be a particular reason for this error to happen occasionally?

Comment: I've been scratching my head over the same issue for several weeks myself. It happens in the field but I cannot reproduce it myself. Happening almost entirely on Android devices, though smatterings of iPhone, Mac and others appearing, just to confuse matters. If you made any progress on this, I'd love to hear it! I even confirmed the template resources in question are being fetched correctly with a 200 OK response according to the Apache access logs, so the browsers have no excuse!

Answer (score 0):

> Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$compile/tpload?p0=app%2Fmyroute%2Fpmyroute.html&p1=-1&p2=

It is a common error. Please check why the URL of template is not resolved at that time. I suggest you turn on the failed request tracing to get the detail error message of failed request.

[image]

**Updated 5/2/2017**

> What am I looking for in the file? I see the request that errored but it gives no insight into what went wrong.

After enabled the detail error messages and failed request tracing, you will see there is a folder named W3SVC1505031315 under LogFiles/ folder. You could download it to your local and open the log xml using IE. You can view the request details by click the [Request Details] tab.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I am just coming back to this. What am I looking for in the file? I see the request that errored but it gives no insight into what went wrong.

Comment: For whatever reason I am not seeing the folder you are talking about. The only folder I see with that style of name is W3SVC902610126 and the logs that are occurring are not being captured in there (I see nLog writing the error but it isn't getting put in Kudu).